# R 4.0.4 Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, cluster, MASS, mgcv, survival

Tags: r

I'm trying to install packages with

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("graph")
BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz")
BiocManager::install("RBGL")
# All other packages are downloaded via CRAN
install.packages(c("rstudioapi","stringr","reshape2","Rgraphviz", "ggplot2","GGally", "gRim"))
```

But this keeps popping:

```
`package ‘RBGL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Ag\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp275oVA\downloaded_packages
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages:
  boot, cluster, MASS, mgcv, survival
> # All other packages are downloaded via CRAN
> install.packages(c("rstudioapi","stringr","reshape2","Rgraphviz", "ggplot2","GGally", "gRim"))
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/Ag/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rgraphviz’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rstudioapi_0.13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 302325 bytes (295 KB)
downloaded 295 KB`
```

I'm using windows and super new in R can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are only showing some of the output, did you cut some off? One thing I see is that `Rgraphviz` should not be in `install.packages()`, that should be in `BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz")` instead. Maybe you are following an outdated guide? What do you see if you run `.libPaths()`?

Comment: @MrFlick Yeah I did cut some off and I just realize that graph, Rgraphviz and RBGL show quite similar errors, and Rgraph is in the BiocManager, so do I just keep it there erasing the other one? and this is what it shows   ``` > .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Ag/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/library"```